# Is there a way in R to create two day aggregates from daily time series data?

Tags: r, data-manipulation

Hi I have time series data that has daily dates (variable 1) and then for each date I have a time variable that is assigned from (1-60). On each day there is a number X events. Is there a way to create a new dataset where 2 day aggregates for my value are summed across and I have 30 rows (time variables) instead of 60?

Update: Here is a reproducible example of what I want

```
set.seed(101)

df <- data.frame(

      dte = c(as.Date("2021-01-01"),
      as.Date("2021-01-02") ,
      as.Date("2021-01-03"),
      as.Date("2021-01-04") ,
      as.Date("2021-02-01") ,
      as.Date("2021-02-02") ,
      as.Date("2021-02-03") ,
      as.Date("2021-02-04")
  ),
tme = rep(c(1, 2, 3, 4)),
val1 = sample(1:8),
work_type = c("Construction Worker", "Construction Worker","Construction 
Worker", "Construction Worker", "Sales", "Sales", "Sales", "Sales"),
Work_Site = "A"
)

print(df)

df_2day <- data.frame(
             tme = rep(c(1, 2)),
             val1 = c(9,13,5,9),
             work_type = c("Construction Worker", "Construction Worker", 
            "Sales", "Sales"),
            Work_Site = "A"
                      )

            print(df_2day)
```

I also have facility B, C, D

Comment: I have provide one above now. Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't the values be 9, 15, 5 and 7? Taking sum of every 2 days (rows) ?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create group of 2 days and `sum` the `val1` values.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Work_Site, work_type, grp = ceiling_date(dte, '2 days')) %>%
  summarise(val1 = sum(val1))

#   Work_Site work_type           grp         val1
#  <chr>     <chr>               <date>     <int>
#1 A         Construction Worker 2021-01-03     9
#2 A         Construction Worker 2021-01-05    15
#3 A         Sales               2021-02-03     5
#4 A         Sales               2021-02-05     7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can identify the groupings by dividing the row number for each day by two and rounding up the the nearest whole number. So the 3rd reading would be 3/2 = 1.5, rounded up to be group 2. The 10th would be 10/2 = group 5.
Below is an implementation using dplyr, but you could use something else...

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
    dte = c(as.Date("2021-01-01"),
                  as.Date("2021-01-01") ,
                  as.Date("2021-01-01"),
                  as.Date("2021-01-01") ,
                  as.Date("2021-02-01") ,
                  as.Date("2021-02-01") ,
                  as.Date("2021-02-01") ,
                  as.Date("2021-02-01")
    ),
    tme = rep(c(1, 2, 3, 4)),
    val1 = sample(1:8),
    val2 = sample(1:8)
)

print(df)

result <- df %>%
    group_by(dte) %>%
    mutate(dategroup=ceiling(rank(tme) / 2)) %>%
    group_by(dte, dategroup) %>%
    summarise_all(sum)

print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks, i have specified my dataset a little more clearly in terms of how it is set up. This code does not seem to work for it. Sorry for not putting an example before